# NSDateFormatter dateFormat ShortStyle not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, nsdateformatter

I have some problem with the NSDateFormatter now.

When I set the dateStyle to be `ShortStyle`, the code will work if I set the language of the simulator into Simplified Chinese. If I set the date is `2015-04-20`, it will show `15/4/20`. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/enum/NSDateFormatterStyle), this result is correct. And since I set the locale of the `dateFormatter`, the date will be shown in a `year/month/date` format, which meets the date writing habit of Chinese.

> ShortStyle
>
> Specifies a short style, typically numeric only, such as “11/23/37”
>   or “3:30 PM”.

If I set the language of the simulator into Japanese, and the same code will lead to the result of `2015/04/20`. This is different with the description of the documentation, but it is working anyway.

However, if I set the language of the simulator into English, the same code will cause an error. The code is showing as the following, and the error says `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`. It points to the line of `let tmpStartDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self.room!.startdate)!`

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let currentTimeZone: NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
dateFormatter.timeZone = currentTimeZone
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
dateFormatter.locale = locale
let tmpStartDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self.room!.startdate)!
let start: String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(tmpStartDate)
```

But this is strange. The same code and the same date will run if the simulator's language is Simplified Chinese or Japanese (though a little bit different). But it will lead to a fatal error in English.

And I have to say that `self.room.startdate` is not nil. It is got from server, and will never be nil in any situation. I can even print it out.

Also, the similar code which uses `ShortStyle` in another view **can work correctly**. I have no idea why this happens.

Does anyone know why this problem happen? And how to solve it if I really want to use the `NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle`, rather than set the `dateFormat` directly into `'yy/MM/dd'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend looked at the code and point out the problem.

This problem is caused by the differences of the date format between Chinese/Japanese and English. In Chinese/Japanese, the date format is `year/month/date`. But in English, the date format is `month/date/year`.

In my code, I set the `dateStyle` into `ShortStyle` before I transfer the date from string. It will work correctly since the start date string is also in a `year-month-date` format. But in English, the `ShortStyle` is `month/date/year`. But the date format of the start date string is still `year-month-date`. And this will lead to the failure of transferring date from string, and cause the application crashes.

To solve this, just move the line `dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle` after the `let tmpStartDate: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self.room!.startdate)!` line.

Then the code will work correctly, and show different date format for different region. (`Year/month/date` for Chinese/Japanese, and `month/date/year` for English.)

Special thanks to my friend SorziaX, though he does not have a stackoverflow account.

Comment: I had mentioned that similar code can work correctly in another view. That is because in that view, I had wrote the code in a correct sequence. And I didn't realize the differences between these views.  Anyway, this will cause different result according to the different date format.